# How to convert this lambda expression to async/await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda

```
public bool Remove()
{
    var itemsToRemove = activeQueue.Where(x => x.Value.CanRemove()).ToArray();
    foreach(var item in itemsToRemove)
        activeQueue.Remove(item.Key);

    return passiveQueue.IsEmpty && activeQueue.Count == 0;
}
```

I want to make `Remove` method awaitable - `public async bool Remove()`. So the only blocking thing is `CanRemove`, which is now returning `Task<bool>`. But I'm not sure how to make it `await`.

UPD:

```
public Task<bool> CanRemove()
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
         ...
         return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the only blocking thing is CanRemove which is now returning Task<bool>"? Can you show `CanRemove`? Does this method involve any IO?

Comment: I mean only place that may block the calling thread. It involves some library calls, which is using synchronous api calls.

Comment: What are you trying to remove? Async calls should primarly be used for I/O calls (think database or file actions).

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that any of this code is truly asynchronous. Why do you need `Remove` to be asynchronous? To not block the UI thread?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: Yes, it's called from UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Remove` does not do any real asynchronous work (e.g. IO), and your concern is that you don't want to block the UI thread, then I suggest that you keep it synchronous (don't use `Task.Run`, `async` and `await` within the method), and only use a thread-pool thread to not block the UI thread within the UI event handler. Here is an example:

```
private async void button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = await Task.Run(() => Remove());
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `Task.Run()`

```
public async Task<bool> Remove()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
             var itemsToRemove = activeQueue.Where(x => x.Value.CanRemove()).ToArray();
             foreach(var item in itemsToRemove)
                 activeQueue.Remove(item.Key);
         });

        return passiveQueue.IsEmpty && activeQueue.Count == 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
   public async Task<bool> Remove()
    {
        for (int i = activeQueue.Count; i>=0; i++)
        {
            var aq = activeQueue[i];
            var canRemove = await aq.Value.CanRemove();
            if (canRemove)
            {
                activeQueue.RemoveAt(i);
            }                    
        }           

        return passiveQueue.IsEmpty && activeQueue.Count == 0;
    }
```

Comment: In other words it's not possible to embed async/await into lambda expressions?

Comment: It is possible (i recommend reading this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/08/10265476.aspx).